# How to test validation of current password in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, tdd

I'm trying to test if the current password is same as in DB.

my simplified controller:

```
class ChangePasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'current_password' => ['required', new CurrentPassword()],
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user->update([
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        ]);

    }
}
```

in my custom CurrentPassword rule i'm checking the hash like this:

```
class CurrentPassword implements Rule
{

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $check = Hash::check($value, auth()->user()->password);
        dump($check);
        return $check;
    }


    public function message()
    {
        return 'Current password is incorrect.';
    }
}
```

and my test for the custom rule is:

```
/** @test */
public function an_authenticated_user_may_change_own_password()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'password' => '1234'
    ]);

    $this->actingAs($user)->patch("/profile/{$user->id}/password", [
        'current_password' => '1234',
        'password' => 'mynewpassword',
        'password_confirmation' => 'mynewpassword'
    ]);

    $this->assertTrue(Hash::check('mynewpassword', $user->fresh()->password));
}
```

unfortunately i'm getting an error:

> 1)
>   Tests\Feature\UpdatePasswordTest::an_authenticated_user_may_change_own_password
>   Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid.

i don't understand why this is happining. My `dump($check);` returns false when i run this test. My $value is '1234' and the auth()->user()->password returns also '1234'. Maybe somebody have an idee what I'm doing wrong.

this test is getting green:

```
 /** @test */
    public function current_password_must_be_valid()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'password' => '1234'
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($user)->patch("/profile/{$user->id}/password", [
            'current_password' => '12345',
            'password' => 'mynewpassword',
            'password_confirmation' => 'mynewpassword'
        ])->assertSessionHasErrors('current_password');

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hash your password in your factory as well, otherwise Eloquent will store it in cleartext (that's why `auth()->user()->password` returns '1234')

```
public function current_password_must_be_valid()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'password' => Hash::make('1234'); // remember to import the Hash facade
    ]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have updated my test but i'm still getting red. `"$2y$04$C8lenwCy6SwJqFsuEcw0LOQpo/jeqGOCkgys2i/NUWzsaBuE3kVTW"
"$2y$04$C8lenwCy6SwJqFsuEcw0LOQpo/jeqGOCkgys2i/NUWzsaBuE3kVTW"
false`. This are my dumps($value // auth()->user()->password // Hash::check) in custom rule.

Comment: `Hash::check` will check the plain text, so `$value` should be plaintext. In your case it seems you hashed it (so it will hash the hash)

so, just to be sure, this should pass: `Hash::check('1234', auth()->user()->password)` in your custom rule, right?

Comment: you're right. $value was also hashed and thats why the test was red. Thank you !